# How to make character jump left or right to a fixed position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a character on which if I press A or D it jumps to left or right, but the problem is it does not jump to the same position consistently.

If I press D it jumps to the right to some position, then restart the scene and press D again, it jumps to the right but ends up at a different position even though I have given the x and y values to it.

Here's my code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{


  public float jumpSpeed;
  public int jumpHeight;
  public float Xincrement;
  public float Zdecrement;

  void Awake()
  {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  }

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {

  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
      GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(Xincrement, jumpHeight, 0) * jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
      GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, jumpHeight, Zdecrement) * jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Time.Deltatime isn't a fixed value, so you could be getting variations from that. Does it work as expected in FixedUpdate with Time.fixedDeltaTime?

Comment: i didn't tried this yet